# Symfony Validator for Alphanumeric

Tags: regex, symfony, symfony-forms

I am trying to only allow alphanumeric fields for a first name using:

```
patientFirstName:
                 - NotBlank: ~
                 - Regex: 
                       pattern: "/[^a-z_\-0-9]/i"
                       htmlPattern: "^[a-zA-Z\-0-9]+$"
                       message: Name must be alphanumeric
```

However it is still allowing characters like "&&&". Is my regex wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing `^`, `$` and `+` (just like your html pattern): `/^[a-z\-0-9]+$/i`

If you do not add them, the regex will match any string if it contains at least one alphanumeric character.

Answer (score 20):

Symfony 3

If you do not want to use regex, you can use @Assert\Type for validator alphanumeric

You can see it in the symfony doc [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Type.html)

```
@Assert\Type(type="alnum")
```

Comment: Nice catch. Very useful :)

Comment: Useful but I want alpha + space